# How to update UILabel with constantly updating data from MQTT publisher?

Tags: ios, swift, event-handling, mqtt

I have a Raspberry Pi with a temperature sensor, that has a python script which constantly publishes the temperature using MQTT, and I have set the interval for every 1sec. In the iOS app I am making I have an MQTTManager class which has an mqttClient that subscribes to its topic and receives the string with the temperature. In the main view of my app I want to display the temperature and have it constantly updated, with the same (or close to the same) speed as the python script is sending it. The idea I have so far is to have the text of a UILabel be updated with the message string from the mqtt client message. I am not sure how update the label text correctly, with every sent publish event. I know I need to set up some kind of event handler for this message but I am not sure how to go about it. Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE: With the code that I have so far. This is my mqttManager:

```
//
//  MQTTManager.swift
//  TemperatureApp
//
//  Created by Radoka on 2/10/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 radoslav.genov.1992. All rights reserved.
//

    import UIKit
    import CocoaMQTT

    class MQTTManager: NSObject, CocoaMQTTDelegate {

    static let singleton = MQTTManager()
    let mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "iOS Device Emulator", host: "192.168.0.101", port: 1883)
    var connected = false

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("MQTT Initilalized")
        mqttClient.username = "user"
        mqttClient.password = "pass"
        mqttClient.keepAlive = 60
        mqttClient.delegate = self
        connect()
    }

    public func connect(){
        if mqttClient.connState != .connected && mqttClient.connState != .connecting {
            mqttClient.connect()
        }
      }

}

extension MQTTManager {
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) {
        //nothing
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        //nothing
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishAck id: UInt16) {
        //nothing
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        if let string = message.string {
            print(string)
        }
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopic topic: String) {
        print("Subscribed to topic: ", topic)
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didUnsubscribeTopic topic: String) {

    }

    func mqttDidPing(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        print("PING")
    }

    func mqttDidReceivePong(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        print("PONG")
    }

    func mqttDidDisconnect(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, withError err: Error?) {
        print("Disconnected with error: ", err!)
    }

    func mqtt(mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnect host: String, port: Int) {
        print("Connected to MQTT server.")
        connected = true
    }

    func subscribeToTopic(topic: String) {
        if mqttClient.connState == .connected {
            print("Subscribe to: ", topic)
            mqttClient.subscribe(topic, qos: CocoaMQTTQOS.qos1)
        } else {
            print("Can't subscribe to \(topic). Not connected.")
        }
    }
}
```

Next this is my MainTableViewController where i have the shared instance of the mqttManager:

```
//
//  MainTableViewController.swift
//  TemperatureApp
//
//  Created by Radoka on 2/9/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 radoslav.genov.1992. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CocoaMQTT
import CoreData


class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    @IBOutlet weak var temperature: UILabel!
    let mqttManager = MQTTManager.singleton 
    var container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    @IBAction func connectionTest(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            mqttManager.connect()
            print("connected")
            mqttManager.subscribeToTopic(topic: "rpi/gpio")
        } else {
            print("not connected")
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 3
    }

    public func setTemperature(){
        //Update text of temperature label 
    }

}
```

In the set temperature method I want to update the text label. Is this the correct way to go about things?

Comment: Update your question with the code you have so far. Clearly explain what help you need with that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might solve it with a simple `Notification`.
First you should add an observer where you want to update such label, doing so:

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // observe temperature
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.init("post_temperature"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (notification) in
        self?.temperature.text = notification.object as? String ?? ""
      }
   }
}
```

and then when you receive the updated temperature from the topic, you should call:

```
extension MQTTManager {
   func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
      if let string = message.string {
          // post temperature
          NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init("post_temperature"), object: string)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I updated my question with the code that I have right now. So as far as I understand the NotificationCenter post should go in my mqttManager, and the addObserver would be in my controller?